# Get a substring in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to get a substring of a string from Hive. I have a string as this one: 2017-06-05 09:06:32.0

What I want is to get the first two digits from hour, that is, 09.
I get the entire hour with this command:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(hora,11) AS subhoras FROM axmugbcn18.bbdd WHERE hora =  '2017-06-05 09:06:32.0'
```

The result of the command is: 09:06:32.0

In order to get only 09 I try this command:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(hora,'\d\d') AS subhoras FROM axmugbcn18.bbdd WHERE hora = '2017-06-05 09:09:32.0'
```

but results are blank.

How can I retrieve only the two digits of hour?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are **several ways** you can extract **`hours`** from `timestamp` value.

***1.Using Substring function:***

```
select substring(string("2017-06-05 09:06:32.0"),12,2);
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 09   |
+------+--+
```

***2.Using Regexp_Extract:***

```
select regexp_Extract(string("2017-06-05 09:06:32.0"),"\\s(\\d\\d)",1);
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 09   |
+------+--+
```

***3.Using Hour:***

```
select hour(timestamp("2017-06-05 09:06:32.0"));
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 9    |
+------+--+
```

***4.Using from_unixtime:***

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-06-05 09:06:32.0'),'HH');
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 09   |
+------+--+
```

***5.Using date_format:***

```
select date_format(string('2017-06-05 09:06:32.0'),'hh');
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 09   |
+------+--+
```

***6.Using Split:***

```
select split(split(string('2017-06-05 09:06:32.0'),' ')[1],':')[0];
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 09   |
+------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
select 
'2017-06-05 09:06:32.0' as t, 
hour('2017-06-05 09:06:32.0'),                               -- output: 9
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-06-05 09:06:32.0'),'HH')  -- output: 09
from table_name;
```

You can either try `hour` or `unixtimestamp` to get the desired result.

Hope this helps :)